# In jQuery Fullcalendar, how to display a list of events for the current month view below the calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have Fullcalendar working nicely in month view, but I'd also like a list of events for the current month (as triggered by navigating calendar months).

Here is my current calendar:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery('#cwcalendar').fullCalendar({
events: 'http://xxxxx.com/json-page.php',
    color: '#d81f59',
    eventColor: '#d81f59',
    theme: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    height: 400,

    columnFormat: {
    month: 'dd' 
  },
    header: {
    left:   'prev',
    center: 'title',
    right:  'next'
},
    buttonIcons: {
    prev: 'left-single-arrow',
    next: 'right-single-arrow',
    prevYear: 'left-double-arrow',
    nextYear: 'right-double-arrow'
},
    views: {
        month: {
            titleFormat: 'MMMM YYYY'
        }
    },
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
    var dataToFind = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    jQuery("td[data-date='"+dataToFind+"']").addClass('activeDay');
},
    eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
        var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="width:100px;height:60px;padding:8px;background:#fff;position:absolute;z-index:10001;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-radius:5px;border-color:#d81f59;">' + calEvent.title + '</div>';
    jQuery("body").append(tooltip);
    jQuery(this).mouseover(function(e) {
        jQuery(this).css('z-index', 10000);
        jQuery('.tooltipevent').fadeIn('500');
        jQuery('.tooltipevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        jQuery('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
        jQuery('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
    });
    },
});
```

An [available view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/) is listMonth, but this doesn't display when used like this in a separate calendar:

```
defaultView: 'listMonth'
```

Question is, do I work on creating a separate calendar in list view and if so how can I integrate it so the list changes according to the month selection in the calendar. Or is there another way to do this?

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

With [clientEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) you can get an array of events for the current view. Using [viewRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/) you can be notified of when the view changes.

Demo @ https://jsfiddle.net/smcnma7j/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var event_list = $('#event_list');

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   // mock events for demo
    events: function(start, end, tz, callback) {
      var events = [];
      var num_events = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 10;
      for (var i = 0; i < num_events; i++) {
        events.push({
          start: moment(start).add(Math.random() * 30, 'days'),
          title: 'Event that starts on'
        });
      }
      callback(events);
    },
    // every time the view updates, update the event list
    viewRender: function(view, element) {
      var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
      handleViewChange(events);
    }
  });

  function handleViewChange(events) {
    event_list.html('');
    var ul = $('<ul/>');
    $.each(events, function(index, event) {
      var li = $('<li/>');
      li.text(event.title + ' ' + event.start.format());
      ul.append(li);
    });
    event_list.html(ul);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @smcd for pointing that out, exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated :)

Comment: sorry I'm a bit lost on how to get the event function to receive the json feed data. Would I do this using ajax, specifying the dataType as 'json'? Put the 'date' in `data:{}` (they're all one day events) and in the success function include `events.push`. Is that right? Would you mind clarifying for me? Many thanks

Comment: You should use your **events: '/json-page.php'** as you had, just have **viewRender** code to notify you when the view renders/changes. I just used the [events as a function vs as a json feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/) for providing random sample data for the demo.